# What are "the dear years" in Redgauntlet?

Tags: archaicisms, scottish-english

"Wandering Willie's Tale" is a short story embedded within Sir Walter Scott's novel "Redgauntlet" (1824). It's written in Scots and/or Scottish English (I'm not certain where those lines are drawn!). The story begins by introducing the character of Sir Robert Redgauntlet:

> Ye maun [must] have heard of Sir Robert Redgauntlet of that Ilk, who lived in
> these parts before the dear years.

What are, or were, the "dear years"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Dear* here is related to *dearth*.

> The average price of wheat during the first 140 years of the present enquiry is 5s 11¾d the quarter¹.
>
> The following years were those of great dearth, the price of wheat rising above 10s the quarter: 1438, 1482, 1527, 1535, 1536.
>
> [*A History of Agriculture and Prices in England*](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/A_History_of_Agriculture_and_Prices_in_E/vkrit2a8SCAC?hl=en&gbpv=1) Vol 3, James E Thorold Rogers; CUP 2011.

The "dear years" are those when a staple food was dear (pricey) because it was in short supply. They are years, perhaps not of famine, but certainly "defective harvests" as my source puts it.

OED has

> **dear
>
> 6.c.** Said of a time or place in which prices for provisions, etc. are high; ***dear year,*** a year of dearth; also of a dealer who charges high prices.

It's not marked obsolete or even rare, but the latest citation is from 1888 in an entry which was updated in December 2020. I suppose even now one might say that a particular shop is "dear" — charging high prices.

---

¹ The "quarter" has varied over the period in question and could be as much as a quarter of a ton (500 pounds) or as little as a quarter of a hundredweight (28 pounds).

Comment: regarding your footnote, now I'm very curious as to why a "hundredweight" was apparently 112 pounds at some point....

Comment: A hundredweight has always been 112 pounds in the Imperial system. I suspect it's to do with it being 8 stone (1 stone = 14 pounds) and a reasonably close number to 100. Why is a stone 14 pounds? Well... that's another question. It was fixed in 1350.

Comment: This sounds very plausible. Thank you. I would be curious to see any evidence for this specific wheat point, though: if "the dear years" just means "the times when things became expensive" then how do we know for sure that it is wheat?

Comment: Actually for Scotland it was probably oats or barley, particularly before the introduction of the potato (I don't know when the story is set). I've adjusted the answer.